# jQuery.kinetic animated move to position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery.kinetic to allow a div to be scrolled within its parent div by dragging the mouse, just like the demo [on the author's site](https://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/)

I want to add a button, which upon clicking it, moves the jQuery.kinetic activated div to a certain position, however I could not find how to do this. I know the scrollLeft and scrollRight methods can be called to change the position, exactly as I want:

```
$("container-selector").kinetic("scrollLeft", 50);
$("container-selector").kinetic("scrollTop", 480);
```

**However** I wish the change in positions to be animated, not immediate like how the code above does it.

Would anybody know how to smoothly move the draggable div to a specified position upon the clicking of a button, and have this animated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the demo page **[HERE](https://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/)**

```
$('#yourButtonIdOrClass').click(function() {
     $('.container-selector').kinetic('start', { velocity: -10 }); // code to move your container
});
```

From the Doc's

> Start movement in the scroll container at a particular velocity.
>   This velocity will not slow until the end method is called.

So you need to call the end() method to stop the div from scrolling either to the end of the right hand side or end of the left hand side, you might want to use the `moved` event and check how much the container has moved something like the below:

```
moved : function() {
   if() // check moved position {
      $('.container-selector').kinetic('end');
   } 
}
```

The above code will go inside the initialization of the plugin.

**NOTE::** you can use the dev tools to check the event listeners attached to the `left` or `right` buttons.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed this code drags the container all the way either to the left or the right, however, how would I get it to stop moving the container when it has reached a specific x.pos? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you so much for your reply. However, I couldn't find this moved event in the jquery.kinetic.js. How do I call it? Could you elaborate your code a little, and include x.pos? If you can :)